# What is functional programming?

Tags: functional-programming

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Functional programming and non-functional programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279/functional-programming-and-non-functional-programming)
>   [What is (functional) reactive programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028250/what-is-functional-reactive-programming)
>   [What is the difference between procedural programming and functional programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277/what-is-the-difference-between-procedural-programming-and-functional-programming)

What is functional programming?

I'm familiar with procedural programming, but I could not understand the concept of functional programming.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279/functional-programming-and-non-functional-programming, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399/how-to-transition-to-functional-programming, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128057/what-are-the-benefits-of-functional-programming

Comment: You suggest you to read this article for a quick introduction : http://blog.summarize-it.com/2019/02/17/functionnal-programming/