# How to use ValueTuple/Tuple as value and make it mutable in Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples

I want to use ValueTuple or Tuple in Dictionary together and to be able to change content/variable. But it says

> Cannot modify the return value of because it is not a variable

Actually, I want to be able to store data in dictionary without creating new class/struct and can change value content by a name(date, IsOk) like below.

This would make really easy to keeping date in a structured way without new types...

[image: Error message]

Comment: maybe consider using `with` though it will create a new instance and doesn’t make the existing instance mutable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression

Comment: ValueTuple is a value type. You could use `Tuple<DateTime, bool>`which is a reference tpye

Comment: New types/classes aren't bad. They have real name that tell what they are really doing and are easy to write. You are now trying something that a.) won't work as you learned and b.)  will get you you into trouble if you somehow get it to work. ValueTuples are struct that means they get copied in most occasions when used. Mutable structs get you in trouble simply don't do it. They is absolutely no need for 
 that here.

Comment: @KlausGütter - though even with tuple there is no setter, and it’s still immutable see eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725158/why-a-tuple-or-a-keyvalueitem-dont-have-a-setter

Comment: Related: [Modify Struct variable in a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255305/modify-struct-variable-in-a-dictionary).

Comment: `dict["bun"] = (dict["bun"].date, true);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thank you very much budy, that's the thing i wanted. You can post as answer i'd mark as accepted  But question has been closed. I looked at that post but it is not quite similar. I didn't even understand it.